# Plotting position data from Simulink in MatLab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have constructed a simulator in Simulink that simulates the position of an object. I want to visualize the X-Y position of this object in a matlab figure.

I exported the X-Y data from Simulink to matlab using the To Workspace block. From this I get an x and y time series data `out.x_pos` and `out.y_pos`. I can plot them against time with

```
plot(out.x_pos)
```

But the following does not work to get an X-Y plot

```
plot(out.x_pos, out.y_pos)
```

What is the best way to produce this X-Y plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one helped me, I will present what I came up with after eventually reaching the right pages on the MATLAB documentation.

The `To Workspace` block exports the data as a timeseries object. This object has the values of the signal as a property called `Data`. To access the property one writes `<object>.Data`, so to obtain the desired X-Y plot one writes

```
plot(out.x_pos.Data, out.y_pos.Data)
```